# Is there a javax.inject.* equivalent to @Assisted

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, jsr330

We're looking at using the JSR-330 javax.inject.* annotations instead of the com.google.inject.* equivalents.  It looks like the JSR-330 standard does not include several features that I've come to love in Guice.

Specifically, I see no support for the @Assisted keyword.  Also, what about @AssistedInject?  Is @Inject able to be placed on multiple constructors?

I'm interested in being vendor neutral, but not at the cost of handy features.  Any recommendations?

Comment: Note that the JSR-330 is only the API, not the implementation.

Comment: I understand that it is only the API.  However, use of @Assisted would be embedded all over our source code.  If it is not part of the API, then we would not be able to "just switch to another DI framework" if need arose.  I do not know much about Spring, but I'm assuming that it has a radically different approach to accomplishing this task.

Comment: It is not part of the API.  If you want true DI framework independency you must code strictly to the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Assisted` is Guice-only. You can use it with JSR 330's `@Inject`. If you don't want the Guice dependency, do manual assisted injection by implementing the factory interface in code.

Comment: That's too bad, perhaps it'll be included in a future revision of the JSR.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to one of your questions:

> Is @Inject able to be placed on multiple constructors?

from [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html)

> Injectable constructors are annotated with @Inject and accept zero or
>   more dependencies as arguments. @Inject can apply to at most one
>   constructor per class.

So I think the answer is no.